# Flattening assets globbed in angular.json

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm packing my webapp with `angular-cli` and my `angular.json` looks like the following:

```
{
 "projects": {
  "example-web": {
   "architect": {
    "build": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
     "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist",
      "assets": [
       "src/favicon.ico", {
        "glob": "**/*.svg",
        "input": "src",
        "output": "/"
       }
      ],
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This is globbing my svgs just fine, but it's replicating my `src` directory hierarchy.  I prefer to organize my sources with nested folders, so I'd really like to instruct `angular-cli` to flatten these assets.  Of course there's other tools I can use, but my question is:

> Does `angular-cli` (`@angular-devkit`) provide a configuration option
>   to flatten assets?